# Is there anyone knows how to resolve the `HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found`?

Tags: java, database, hibernate, orm

I’ve a question about my application which chooses Hibernate as its ORM framework.
Below are 2 entities in this application:

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “tb_order”)
public class Order {
        
    @Column(name=“id”)
    private String id;

    @Column(name=“product_id”)
    private String product_id;

    @ManyToOne
    @JoinColumn(name = “special_id”, referencedColumnName = “special_id”, insertable = false, updatable = false)
    @Fetch(FetchMode.JOIN)
    private User user;
}
```

```
@Entity
@Table(name = “tb_user”)
public class User {
        
    @Column(name=“id”)
    private String id;
    
    @Column(name=“name”)
    private String name;

    @Column(name=“email”)
    private String email;

    @Column(name=“special_id”)
    private String specialId;

    @Column(name=“status”)
    private String status;
}
```

As you can see there is a many-to-one relationship between `Order` and `User`, and the referenced column is `special_id`.

Now I’m encountering the HibernateException: More than one row with the given identifier was found: null (null), for class: com.example.model.User

The root cause of this issue is that **a special_id can refer to not only one row in the User table**, but I can ensure **one special_id can only refer to one row whose status is `Active`**.

I want to ask whether I can filter the data in User’s result set to only keep the `Active` one before the User’s data is joined with Order, so that I can avoid the above HibernateException

Hard to describle what i've tried.

Comment: that id being there several times is your problem.

Comment: Why not adjust your SQL to bring back unique single copy , drop duplicates.

Answer (score 0):

What about google

```
@Where(clause = "active = 1")
```

https://thorben-janssen.com/hibernate-tips-filter-entities-mapped-association/